# Where is max process size specified?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory, 64bit, x86

I've got a RHEL4 machine with 1TB of memory and have discovered that malloc and mmap refuse to allocate any memory above 512GB. Meanwhile, I don't seem to have a problem with RHEL5 machines. I'm presuming, then, that it's just a matter of kernel configuration. Does anyone know what controls the maximum process size (assuming a fixed page size)?

Comment: RHEL4 is a few years old now... perhaps older versions cannot go this high

Comment: Also 1TB is a lot of memory..

Comment: Yes it is but our domain requires it. And yes 1TB is a lot of memory. Actually, we'll probably need up to 4TB soon.

Comment: Is all the memory recognized by the hardware (say in the BIOS)?  Exactly which version/update level is your RHEL4 at?  Which kernel are you using?

Comment: There are certain limits for code, data and stack segments. You can view them with `ulimit -a` and change them up to another limit. After that you need at least recompile the kernel, maybe some libs too.

Comment: Linux <mach> 2.6.9-89.ELsmp #1 SMP Mon Apr 20 10:33:05 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. Yes BIOs recognizes all the memory and the kernel seems to be able to use all of it, just not all in 1 process.

Comment: I realize that the kernel may need to be recompiled. That's why I asked what option needs to change when I recompile. Or, how can I find out what it is from the kernel headers installed on the system.

Comment: @ott-- I don't see why one need to recompile a kernel after changing security limits with `ulimit`. Still +1 for `ulimit` suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [initial port of Linux for amd64](http://svn.exactcode.de/linux24-psionw/trunk/Documentation/x86_64/mm.txt) only supported a 40-bit virtual address space, divided in 512GB for the process and 512GB for the kernel. [Current versions](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt) support 48 bits of virtual address space, divided in 128TB/128TB. This last limitation is intrinsic in the current version of the amd64 architecture: there is simply no way to configure the [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit#x86-64) to make more bits significant. See [How does Linux support more than 512GB of virtual address range in x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246559/how-does-linux-support-more-than-512gb-of-virtual-address-range-in-x86-64) for an explanation of the amd64 MMU, or the [AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/24593_APM_v2.pdf) (§5.1) for the full story.

I don't know exactly when this limitation changed, but your 2.6.9 kernel is really old. Red Hat publishes a [table of features and limits](http://www.europe.redhat.com/products/rhel/compare/index.php) for RHEL 3 through RHEL 6. The maximum per-process address space on RHEL4 is 512GB. RHEL5 will get you 2TB, but you might want to upgrade directly to RHEL6 which supports the full 128TB.

Comment: From the doc, looks like it changed in 2.6.11.